# What is the difference between .deb package file and ddeb package file in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, dpkg

I need to install  SystemTap in Ubuntu 14  and I would need to install debug symbols for kernel. I encountered a [ddeb](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/) file.

I got this error:

`ERROR: Build-id mismatch [man error::buildid]: after  installation of ddeb file .(kernel version mismatch)`

#### Question:

How could I uninstall this file after installation?